# Type error calling select Standard ML

Tags: sockets, select, sml

I'm trying to call `Socket.select` to deal with some sockets. It seems like the following minimal snippet from my code should work...

```
fun descs ss = map Socket.sockDesc ss

fun selecting server clients =
    let val { ss, ws, cs } = Socket.select {
        rds = descs [server],
        wds = descs [],
        exs = descs clients,
        timeout = (SOME (Time.fromSeconds 10))
        }
    in
    (ss, ws, cs)
    end
```

... but doesn't when I evaluate it in `SML/NJ`:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Thu Feb 19 00:37:13 2015]
- fun descs ss = map Socket.sockDesc ss ;;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val descs = fn : ('a,'b) Socket.sock list -> Socket.sock_desc list
- fun selecting server clients =
    let val { ss, ws, cs } = Socket.select {
        rds = descs [server],
        wds = descs [],
        exs = descs clients,
        timeout = (SOME (Time.fromSeconds 10))
        }
    in
    (ss, ws, cs)
    end ;;
= = = = = = = = = [autoloading]
[autoloading done]
stdIn:3.13-8.7 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: {exs:Socket.sock_desc list, rds:Socket.sock_desc list,
                    timeout:Time.time option, wrs:Socket.sock_desc list}
  operand:         {exs:Socket.sock_desc list, rds:Socket.sock_desc list,
                    timeout:Time.time option, wds:Socket.sock_desc list}
  in expression:
    Socket.select
      {rds=descs (server :: nil),wds=descs nil,exs=descs clients,
       timeout=SOME (Time.fromSeconds 10)}
- 
-
```

Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for leading you a bit astray with the typo in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan - Heh. No worries; the real problem was that I hadn't seen MLs' record syntax before. I've submitted a pull request to [the appropriate `x` in `y`](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/standard-ml/) so that it's less confusing next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Thanks to `bgates` from `#sml` for pointing me in the right direction here)*

Two problems with the above. Firstly, I had a typo in the constructor name in the call to `Socket.select`.

```
...
 rds = descs [server],
 wrs = descs [],  (* `wrs` instead of `wds` here *)
 exs = descs clients,
...
```

Secondly, when pattern-matching on records, you must use the slot-names of the record rather than arbitrary symbols. So

```
...
    let val { ss, ws, cs } = Socket.select {
...
```

should actually be

```
...
    let val { rds, wrs, exs } = Socket.select {
...
```

With those changes...

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Thu Feb 19 00:37:13 2015]
- fun descs ss = map Socket.sockDesc ss ;;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val descs = fn : ('a,'b) Socket.sock list -> Socket.sock_desc list
- fun selecting server clients =
    let val { rds, exs, wrs } = Socket.select {
        rds = descs [server],
        wrs = descs [],
        exs = descs clients,
        timeout = (SOME (Time.fromSeconds 10))
        }
    in
    (rds, wrs, exs)
    end ;;
= = = = = = = = = [autoloading]
[autoloading done]
val selecting = fn
  : ('a,'b) Socket.sock
    -> ('c,'d) Socket.sock list
       -> Socket.sock_desc list * Socket.sock_desc list * 
          Socket.sock_desc list
-
```